# Assign captured group to value, and if no match: assign string

Tags: regex, perl, capturing-group

In Perl regex, [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches) says

> ... in scalar context, `$time =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/` returns a true
>   or false value. In list context, however, it returns the list of
>   matched values `($1,$2,$3)`

But how is it that when you provide an alternative option - when no match is found - TRUE or FALSE will be assigned even when in list context?

As an example, I want to assign the matched group to a variable and if not found, use the string value ALL.

```
my ($var) = $string =~ /myregex/ || 'ALL';
```

Is this possible? And what about multiple captured groups? E.g.

```
my ($var1, $var2) = $string =~ /(d.t)[^d]+(d.t)/ || 'dit', 'dat';
```

Where if the first group isn't matched, `'dit'` is used, and if no match for the second is found `'dat'`.

Comment: Does it have to be a one liner? An `if` `else` and using `$1` and `$2` will probably be more readable

Comment: @Recct It doesn't have to be - as long as it's efficient.

Comment: Also after the `||` those are in void context if everything on the left is false, even if you use the weaker `or` assumedly to be applied if the regex fails still nothing happens on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first requirement, you can use the ternary operator:

```
my $string = 'abded';
for my $f ('a' .. 'f') {
    my ($v1) = $string =~ /($f)/ ? ($1) : ('ALL') ;
    say "$f : $v1";
}
```

**Output:**

```
a : a
b : b
c : ALL
d : d
e : e
f : ALL
```